# Hover doesn't follow mouse until click

Tags: macos, imac, mouse

The best way to explain it is... You know how when you're at the dock and you put your mouse over something and it magnifies it? It doesn't do that for me, I have magnification turned on yet that feature doesn't work unless if I click on an app then it will magnify until I stop clicking it. It's happened to me in games too. I can't move the camera/mouse unless if I click first.

How do I fix this?

iMac, OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Answer (score 1):

OP here. (made an account). I already found a solution to my question thanks to the editor who used the title "Hover doesn't follow mouse until click" It turned out to be an issue with my RAT 7 drivers. Apparently, Yosemite messed up a few things. An update fixed it, thankfully! 
http://madcatz.com/downloads/

Comment: Glad you found a solution!  You should mark this as answered (even though you found the answer yourself) so others with the same problem can find the solution.  Just a suggestion too, update the question with the mouse hardware and software you were having the issue with.

Comment: Actually, if there's a question and answer that already addressed this, this question should be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The "update" from MadCatz didn't help, the most recent version of their driver supports OS X 10.9 (not 10.10). I believe that driver is version 1.1.69. Whatever it is, the most recent version does not work at all on 10.10 and doesn't even install on 10.11.